# How to call a method in try with resources

Tags: java, try-with-resources, try-finally

I was using try..finally code but I want to use try with resource but I am not sure how to call a method in try with resource can anyone help me with that?

using try finally

```
try{
}
catch{}
finally{
//closed a resources 
//called a methods 
reportAbc();

}
```

using Try with resource

```
try(){
}
catch{}
```

but I am not sure how should I call reportAbc() method without using finally.

Comment: Why can't it be in a `finally` block still? Perhaps you should provide a [mre] demonstrating what you're trying to do.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `finally`? And what resource are you closing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is from the documentation:

> Note: A try-with-resources statement can have catch and finally blocks just like an ordinary try statement. In a try-with-resources statement, any catch or finally block is run after the resources declared have been closed.

[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html#:~:text=Note%3A%20A%20try%20%2Dwith%2D,resources%20declared%20have%20been%20closed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html#:%7E:text=Note%3A%20A%20try%20%2Dwith%2D,resources%20declared%20have%20been%20closed).

Answer (score 2):

As the [correct Answer by MaxG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69399823/642706) said, your resources are closed in between leaving the code block and entering either `catch` or `finally` block.

The Question’s example code is incomplete with faulty syntax. Here is a full example.

```java
try
(
    SomeResource someResource = … ;
)
{
    someResource.reportAbc() ;
    …

}
catch
{
    // someResource will have been closed by this point.
    …
}
finally
{
    // someResource will have been closed by this point.
    …

}
```

Notice the pair of parentheses for declaring resources. Those objects must implement [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html). Multiple resources will be closed in the reverse order in which they were listed in the parentheses.